# PHP proc_open not receiving data from Go script

Tags: php, go, reactphp

I'm currently using the ReactPHP Child-Process library (which uses proc_open()) to get data from a Go application in stream format. However, when I dump all input from stdout and stderr, I get nothing even though when I test it in bash I get output.

Here is the Go script: https://github.com/bwmarrin/dca/blob/master/main.go

The Go script uses goroutines so that may be the issue? (Not sure, I'm not a Go developer and I didn't make the program.)

I'm running on Mac OS X 10.11.2 El Capitan with PHP 7.0.3 CLI.

PHP Code:

```
$loop = Factory::create();

$process = new Process("dca -i /Users/david/Music/Zombies.mp3");

$process->start($loop);
$process->stdout->on('data', function ($data) {
    var_dump($data);
});
$process->stderr->on('data', function ($data) {
    dump($data);
});

$loop->run();
```

React Child-Process can be found here: https://github.com/reactphp/child-process

Comment: Post php code related to the question please.

Comment: @dezhik thanks, added

Comment: It is not related to the use of goroutines. As this programs works with unix pipes specifically, you might need to attach the process to a shell instead of running it directly.

Comment: Does the program output when you run it directly on the command line?  There doesn't appear to be anything broken with the Go code.  Besides that `dump()` is not a built-in PHP function, so are you certain that function is doing what you expect?

Comment: @Sean Yeah, it works fine in the command line. `dump()` is just a function that comes with `symfony/var-dumper`.

Comment: @thwd Pretty new to using that stuff haha, how would I attach the process to a shell?

Comment: My next recommendation would be making sure your path is correct.  So instead of assuming that the application has the correct PATH, try putting in the full path.  ex. `/usr/local/bin`.  If you don't know what it is just use `which dca` to find it.

Comment: @thwd sorry for the bump, i still haven't got it working and was wondering if you would be able to help me to "attach the process to a shell"?

Comment: @cheese5505 no problem, for example `new Process("bash -c 'dca -i /Users/david/Music/Zombies.mp3'");`

Comment: @thwd still the same problem :(